# How to display xclock on another computer?

Tags: x11, remote, lxde, display

I want to display `xclock` on another computer.

On my computer (`111`) I am able to `ping` the other computer (`222`) inside my home network:

```
$ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:55:66:77:88:99  
          inet addr:192.168.0.111  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
$ ping 192.168.0.222
```

The router is a D-Link [DIR-655 Wireless N Gigabit Router](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/home-solutions/connect/routers/dir-655-wireless-n-gigabit-router).

```
$ xclock -display 192.168.0.111:0
```

Displays the `xclock` on my computer (`111`) as expected. On the other computer (`222`):

```
$ xhost +
```

But then back on my computer (`111`) it also displays on my computer when changed to:

```
$ xclock -display 192.168.0.222:0
```

To attempt to verify the use of the `-display` switch:

```
$ xclock -display 192.168.0.111:0.1
Error: Can't open display: 192.168.0.111:0.1
$ ping 192.168.0.333
ping: unknown host 192.168.0.333
$ xclock -display 192.168.0.333:0
```

I would expect it to fail but it also displays on my computer (`111`) but with a bit of a delay. These results tells me that the `display` argument is getting to `xclock`.

```
$ uname -a
 Linux mycomputer 3.2.0-27-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 6 14:46:35 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I am using [LXDE](http://lxde.org/) rather than GNOME or KDE.

I am only attempting to get `xclock` to display and am not interested in addressing security issues in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my computer (`111`):

```
ssh -X 192.168.0.222
```

followed simply by:

```
xclock
```

will run `xclock` on the other computer (`222`) and display on my computer (`111`).

Note: For this to work `X11Forwarding` should be enabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` at computer (`222`)

Answer (score 5):

Two things to check for: Port 6000 needs to be open on the 222 machine (configure or disable the firewall), and the X server itself needs to be listening on that port. This is often disabled in modern distros. Check if it's listening with

```
# netstat -nltp | grep 6000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10818/Xorg          
tcp6       0      0 :::6000                 :::*                    LISTEN      10818/Xorg
```

If not, you can enable it for gdm in /etc/gdm/custom.conf

```
[security]
DisallowTCP=false
```

Logout/restart gdm on the 222 machine and log in again. You should then see Xorg listening on port 6000.

Comment: '/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and add xserver-allow-tcp=true ' for LXDE from http://askubuntu.com/questions/72812/how-to-disable-nolisten

Answer (score 1):

And you can do simplest :)

```
$ ssh -X 192.168.0.222 "xclock"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated answer. It worked for me on fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.02.

I installed ssh server to make the system accessible on ssh.

Nothing is blocked by default, to verify it. So nothing to do.
`iptables -L`

I opened the file `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` and added

```
[security]
DisallowTCP=false
```

I uncomment the following in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

I restarted the machine and run the command `xhost +`

Now I went to the second computer and run the command, make sure xclock is installed and assuming that output of command `echo $DISPLAY` is :1

```
xclock -display IP_Address:1
```

You will see the xclock on the ubuntu computer.

`netstat -antlp | grep 6001` was showing Xorg listening.